# Checking if a value from window.getSelection matches a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a text editor but want to do an action when someone starts to type inside a paragraph tag that contains an image or has a certain class.

Using:

```
sel = window.getSelection();
var p = sel.baseNode.parentNode;
```

I can console.log p and see as an example:

```
<p>this is a paragraph</p>
```

However, when ever I try to check the 'p' var against anything in a if statement it doesn't match. Niether does indexOf as it says indexOf is not a function of p.

Any help?

Specifically, looking to check if the p var string contains class="has-image"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I deleted my last Answer, because I misunderstood your problem.
This is the solution:

You are looking for the `sel.baseNode.parentNode.nodeName`

And to check the class: `sel.baseNode.parentNode.className`

Comment: Man, im sure it looked through every ounce of information that the baseNode returned but didn't see a class name.

Comment: check here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp
&& http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp

Comment: You can edit your deleted answer, then click on undelete, rather than post a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery `hasClass()` function.

```
$(p).hasClass("has-image")
```